Что делать, если при покупке HDD на нем стоит пароль?
На маркет плейсе купил HDD
Toshiba NAS N300 4TB
HDWQ140UZSVA
Забрал заказ, подключил к ПК и при загрузке ПК вылазиет ввод пароля

Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь. Пароль на HDD, да еще на новом.
Пробовал на двух ПК, эффект тот же.
Если попытаюсь подключить на "горячую" при включенной ОС (Windows 10 на двух ПК), то HDD громко гудит и ведет себя странно. То определяется, то не определяется.

ну пароль наверное на HDD написан.... а если нет - то продавцу напишите

ну а вообще через bios вроде можно и это через поисковик находится легко https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-disable-an-hdd-password-in-a-laptop    .....  https://lumpics.ru/how-to-remove-password-from-hdd/    .....  https://yandex.ru/search/?text=how+to+remove+password+from+hdd&clid=2270485&win=657&lr=213

Странно видеть "новый" hdd, который уже лет 6 назад сняли с производства. Есть мнение, что это либо восстановленный, либо просто подделка.

Сдать его нужно назад.
